# php/apache update and code broke

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

Some server info:
Apache version
WAS Apache 2.2.26
NOW IS Apache 2.4.7

PHP version
WAS 5.3.28   ( DEPRECATED )
NOW IS 5.4.25

after the update a plugin used something like this:

`$args['headers']['X-WP-Domain'] = self::domain();`

and then

`$request = wp_remote_request( $url, $args );`

on the request url we have something like:

```
    if ( $wp->query_vars['wpec'] != 'notification' && ( empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_WP_DOMAIN'] ) || $_SERVER['HTTP_X_WP_DOMAIN'] != home_url() ) ) {
    throw new Exception( 'Invalid domain', 500 );
}
```

$wp->query_vars['wpec'] will be = purchase so first clause is right.
but somehow that if clause is throwing us the error 500 Invalid domain.

X-WP-Domain is set as you can see and it does match home_url() so the && clause is met too

Comment: Add `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_WP_DOMAIN']` to that exception to see what it holds.

Comment: i tried that too and it holds the exact thing as requested at first by self::domain(); the plguins "workflow" is a bit complicated but the vars are set

Comment: OK, and you are sure your `home_url()` function is working correctly as well? (Also add that to the Exception, possibly base64_encode() them both to see slight differences in character sets or whitespace).

Comment: You really need to learn some debugging skills. Try: `var_dump($wp->query_vars['wpec'] != 'notification'); var_dump($wp->query_vars['wpec'] != 'notification'); var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WP_DOMAIN'] != home_url());` and your error should be made apparent.

Comment: bool(true) bool(true) bool(true)